# audit2allow asks for a path when setting up nginx

Tags: nginx, selinux

To setup nginx on centos7, I used to run:

```
grep nginx /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M nginxse
```

and it worked fine, but apparently on an updated system, it is different. audit2allow complains:

```
You must specify the -p option with the path to the policy file.
```

How can I do use it as before to fix the security policy problem?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently selinux was disabled on this new machine so the audit log had no errors which is why the command failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out:https://www.linode.com/docs/quick-answers/linux/how-to-install-selinux-on-ubuntu-18-04/#install-selinux
You also need to go here after installing selinux to download python3-setools_4.1.1-3_amd64.deb and install it
https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/python3-setools_4.1.1-3_amd64.deb.html
When I did this on Ubuntu18.04, I was able to use the audit2allow tool normally.
My English is not good, I used the translation software to translate this, sorry.